# How to format strings with jinja/ansible?

Tags: ansible, jinja2

Friends,

I am learning Ansible here and trying to apply what I am learning to one of my simple projects. I got stuck trying to format some strings. I getting the following error:

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": 
"AnsibleError: template error while templating string: 
**unexpected ']', expected ')'**. 

String: 

cluster_name = \"{{ terraform['%s' | format(env)].cluster_name }}\"
\ncredentials = \"{{ terraform['%s' | format(env)].credentials }}\"
\ninitial_node_count = \"{{ terraform['%s' | format(env]].initial_node_count }}
\format(env)].project }}\""}
    ...
```

This is how my jinja2 file looks like:

```
cluster_name = "{{ terraform['%s' | format(env)].cluster_name }}"
credentials = "{{ terraform['%s' | format(env)].credentials }}"
initial_node_count = "{{ terraform['%s' | format(env]].initial_node_count }}"
...
```

I want to generate strings like this `terraform['testing'].credentials` when I run `ansible-playbook site.yaml -e env=testing`and write them to a file. I can't figure out another way to get this done. Any Idea?

Comment: Please clarify: Do you want to write the value of the variable `terraform.testing.cluster_name` (that is elswhere set in your playbook/environment) in the resulting file, or do you want to write the literal string `"terraform['testing'].cluster_name"` ? Note: it the first answer is what you want, @Richard Sellam as already given the correct answer below. Also, please edit your question and fix the formating of your error message. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you want to use this syntax:

```
cluster_name = "{{ terraform[env].cluster_name }}"
```

With `terraform.env`, ansible will get the env key of the terraform env, but with `terraform[env]`
, ansible will resolve env to 'testing' and get the 'testing' key of the terraform var.

Answer (score 1):

Q: **"*Generate strings like this `terraform['testing'].credentials`*"**

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook site.yaml -e env=testing
```

A: The playbook below

```yaml
shell> cat site.yml
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        cluster_name: "{{ begin }}{{ env }}{{ end }}"
      vars:
        begin: "terraform['"
        end: "'].credentials"
    - debug:
        var: cluster_name
```

gives

```yaml
  cluster_name: terraform['testing'].credentials
```

Comment: merely for your consideration, AFAIK that's equivalent to `cluster_name: terraform['{{ env }}'].credentials` but without the indirection